# Insert Image in parse template crossrider Extension

Tags: html, image, popup, crossrider

How i can insert an Image into a html in crossrider.

I have a html template which i will parse it later . in that html i need to have a image.

Let me know how. i tried like below but not able to succeed

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- This meta tag is relevant only for IE -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="tubevid_formats">
        <div id='close_span'>&times;</div>
            <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Download Links</h1>
                <ul>
                    <% for (var i=0; i<vids.length; i++) { %>
                    <li>
                        <a id="format" href="<%=vids[i]['url'] %>"><%=vids[i]['type']%> - <%=vids[i]['pixels']%>Px - <%=vids[i]['size']%> </a>
                       <div class="dwn-icon"><img src="<%= appAPI.resources.get('img/download.png')%>" alt=""></div>
                    </li>
                    <% } %>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am parsing the above html as below and injecting the formatted code into a div in web page

```
       var formats = appAPI.resources.parseTemplate("formats.html",result);
        $('#tubevid_div').html('');
        $code=$(formats);
        $('#tubevid_div').prepend($code);
```

Comment: you have to use JS or jQuery Code inside of the Crossrider Extension. Then just append the image-Tag.

Comment: I have done that using Jquery, you can see it from above code. but my image failed to load and my doubt is how to load image from resources folder to html which i am going to parse

Comment: In order to help, please provide some context and related code showing how the html is opened/injected. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: @Shlomo updated the code, let me know if you need anything in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the updated code.

The HTML you are injecting runs in the HTML Page's DOM scope and does not have access to the *extension.js* scope; hence, [appAPI.resources.get](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources-method-get) is undefined and does not work in your example.

To achieve your goal, you can try adding the resource before injecting the HTML into the page scope. Since you are using [appAPI.resources.parseTemplate](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources-method-parseTemplate), I suggest you pass the resource as part of your **result** object.

So, using your code snippet, the HTML would look like:

```
<div id="tubevid_formats">
  <div id='close_span'>&times;</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Download Links</h1>
    <ul>
      <% for (var i=0; i<vids.length; i++) { %>
        <li>
          <a id="format" href="<%=vids[i]['url'] %>"><%=vids[i]['type']%> - <%=vids[i]['pixels']%>Px - <%=vids[i]['size']%> </a>
          <div class="dwn-icon"><img src="<%=resImage%>" alt=""></div>
        </li>
      <% } %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

... and the code:

```
result.resImage = appAPI.resources.get('img/download.png');
var formats = appAPI.resources.parseTemplate("formats.html",result);
$('#tubevid_div').html('');
$code=$(formats);
$('#tubevid_div').prepend($code);
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: it didn't worked as expected. did you tested it. it is injecting content of image instead of location of image.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get a chance to test it and the earliest I'll be able to do so is on Sunday. Did the image appear? You can't specify the **src** as a URL to a resource file in this context since the page scope does not have access to the extension's resources; hence you must embed the resource image into the HTML as shown.

Comment: I tested the sample code snippet and it works. Please check that your code defines the **result** object and that the resources exist in your extension.

Comment: i am getting some symbols.. not the image.. any way i inserted the image in my result object from my server by keeping image in my server